# Trying to understand SSL Handshake

Tags: ssl, handshake

I have two servers communicating over SSL. server1 initiates a SSL connection to server2 over SSL. server1 has a keystore with a keysize of 1k whereas server2 has a keystore with a keysize of 2k. Will the SSL channel get established or will it fail ? Where exactly in the handshake does this exchange or negotiation take place ?

Answer (score 0):

> I have two servers communicating over SSL. server1 initiates a SSL connection to server2 over SSL.

So in this case `server1` is the client of `server2.`

> server1 has a keystore with a keysize of 1k whereas server2 has a keystore with a keysize of 2k.

The sizes are irrelevant.

> Will the SSL channel get established or will it fail?

Impossible to say with just this amount of information. What happened when you tried it? The important thing is that `server2` has a key pair and a certificate in its keystore that is trusted by `server1's` truststore.

> Where exactly in the handshake does this exchange or negotiation take place?

Err, the handshake *is* the negotiation. The question doesn't make sense.

Comment: The certs for both servers are signed by a CA and both the servers trust the CA. Can you expand on your statement "sizes are irrelevant" ? Can you pass on a link to some doc that states so ?

Comment: The phases of the moon aren't relevant either, but I don't expect to to find a document that says so, or to be asked for one. You're the one that thinks it's relevant. Show me. Cite a document that says so.

Comment: Leaving your irrelevant remarks aside, the point is that there isn't in general a document that says X isn't relevant to Y. Otherwise there would have to be an infinity of them, because X *isn't* relevant to Y, for most values of X and Y. In other words your request didn't make sense. Don't shoot the messenger.